# AngularJS insert video in HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

```html
<video ng-src="{{user_detail.cv_video}}" controls>
    Votre navigateur n'est pas compatible avec le HTML 5, désolé.
</video>
```

I have tried this code in order to insert a video from server in my html but it went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: pls refer this before posting your query http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Comment: What went wrong? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any further information, one of the common issue about this matter is that the URL is not listed as safe.

Create trust Filter:

```
app.filter("trustUrl", ['$sce', function ($sce) {
        return function (url) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
        };
    }]);
```

In View File:

```
<video ng-src="{{user_detail.cv_video | trustUrl}}" controls>
    Votre navigateur n'est pas compatible avec le HTML 5, désolé.
</video>
```